# No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'ExtractImagePatches' on Android

Tags: android, tensorflow, yolo

I trained YOLOv2 to detect objects and I want to deploy this on Android.

**1.** So I changed it to pb file by using this command in darkflow.

`./flow --model cfg/yolo-obj.cfg --load bin/yolo-obj.weights --savepb`

**2.** Then I referred to [this page](http://seangtkelley.me/blog/2017/12/23/using-custom-yolov2-model-on-android), so I changed some part in DetectorActivity.java and TensorFlowYoloDetector.java

When I execute this, it occurred this error.

> E/TensorFlowInferenceInterface: Failed to run TensorFlow inference with inputs:[input], outputs:[output]
>
> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: inference
>       Process: org.tensorflow.demo, PID: 19051
>       java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'ExtractImagePatches' used by {{node ExtractImagePatches}}with these attrs: [padding="VALID", T=DT_FLOAT, ksizes=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], rates=[1, 1, 1, 1]]

**3.** To solve this problem, I referred to [a page](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/10153), so I added `extract_image_patches_op.cc` and `extract_image_patches_op.h` in `android_core_ops` of `tensorflow/core/kernels/BUILD`. And then I did this part

```
 bazel clean && \
        bazel build -c opt //tensorflow/contrib/android:libtensorflow_inference.so \
--crosstool_top=//external:android/crosstool \
--host_crosstool_top=@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:toolchain \
--cpu=armeabi-v7a
```

**4.** I added `libtensorflow_inference.so` file on Android but It still occurred error

> No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'ExtractImagePatches'

How can I solve this??

Thank you in advance.